# Change the root directory of rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, digital-ocean

My server is on http://digitalocean.com

Currently my Rails directory is pointed to `/home/rails/rails_projects/`

but I need the default directory to be `/home/rails/newProject/`

I also installed rails 4.2.2 and made it default version.

How would I do that?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to answer your question.  Are you using a DigitalOcean 1-click droplet image?  If so, can you link to which one.  You don't say which server you're using, or how you deploy, or how your environment was configured in the first place.  This is just too broad of a question.

Comment: Usually the directory is a function of your virtual host configuration, so I'd check there first.

Comment: By "default directory", do you mean the directory that's storing the served application for your server?

Comment: Try change `ENV['HOME']`

Comment: Why to you need the path name to be change? What do you try to achieve? Who set the directly in the first place (you or DigitalOcean)?

Comment: Please complete the question. What are you using? NGINX? APACHE? no one can answer without server information.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change `Rails.root` to a different directory you can give it a relative path.  In your case it would be:

`Rails.application.config.root = "../newProject"`

Answer (score 0):

When to change the root so that the rails application redirects to your path, you have to configure the `routes.rb` present in `config`.

It should be :

```
root 'controller_name#method_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 or Rails 4:

```
Rails.root
```

which returns a `Pathname` object. If you want a string you have to add .to_s. If you want another path in your Rails app, you can use join like this:

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'logo.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is digital ocean server and you know only this much than it may be deployed with nginx. For that you should go to

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

file and there you would see line like this

```
root /home/rails/rails_projects/
```

change it to

```
root /home/rails/newProject/
```

similar steps would go for apache.